# How to stop a Mediaplayer when i press Home, BUT not in an other activity

Tags: android, button, android-intent, android-activity, media-player

first, sorry for my bad English
With my code, I can stop the Mediaplayer when the home button is pressed, but I also stop it when I "open" an other activity.
Then, i just want to know if i can stop the Mediaplayer ( mpFond in my code ) when I press Home button, but not when I open an other activity.

Here's my code:

```
private MediaPlayer mpFond;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//some code

        mpFond = MediaPlayer.create(AccueilActivity.this,R.raw.accueil);    
        mpFond.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mpFond.setLooping(true);
        mpFond.start();

        // "definition" des boutons
    Button play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play);

    //some code

    play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { // LE BOUTON JOUER

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            //Lorsqu'on clique sur "JOUER" 
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(AccueilActivity.this,R.raw.bruit);
            mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            //if silent mode
            switch (am.getRingerMode()) {
            case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT:
                mp.setVolume(0,0);
                break;
            }
            //demarrage du son
            mp.start();

            Intent intent = new Intent(app, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    });
//some code
}

//some code

@Override
public void onPause()
{
   super.onPause();
   if(mpFond.isPlaying()){
   mpFond.pause();
   }

}

@Override
public void onStop()
{
   super.onStop();
  if(mpFond.isPlaying()){
    mpFond.stop();
  }
}
```

Comment: You mean you do not want to stop it when you switch it from music activity to another activity?

Comment: I dont have a music activity, i start my mediaplayer mpFond in this activity ( it's like a "welcome activity" with buttons like "play" "exit" "about" ), and i want it to continu even if i press "PLAY" (so, even if i change my activity)

Comment: Without onPause() and onStop(), it continues when i press "play", but then, it also continues when i press the device home button :( That's my problem ...

Comment: You mean in the app, you continue the music; out the app,stop the music?

Comment: Yeah, in app, even if i change the activity, i continue the music, and out the app, i stop it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is ok now. Just found the way to do that :

```
@Override
public void onPause()
{
   super.onPause();
   if(mpFond.isPlaying()this.isFinishing()){
   mpFond.pause();
}

}

 @Override
public void onStop()
{
   super.onStop();
  if(this.isFinishing(){
    mpFond.stop();
  }
}
```